# Cannot get past "paranamer" error with JlinkPlugin in sbt-native-packager

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, sbt-native-packager, jlink

We're trying to include a minimal *JDK* as part of a *Windows* installer for a *Play* 2.8.8 application, using the version of *sbt-native-packager* included with *Play*.

Alas, when packaging the application, we get the following error.

```
[error] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.module.FindException: Module paranamer not found, required by com.fasterxml.jackson.module.paranamer
[error]         at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.findFail(Resolver.java:877)
[error]         at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.resolve(Resolver.java:191)
[error]         at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.resolve(Resolver.java:140)
[error]         at java.base/java.lang.module.Configuration.resolve(Configuration.java:422)
[error]         at java.base/java.lang.module.Configuration.resolve(Configuration.java:256)
[error]         at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.JdepsConfiguration$Builder.build(JdepsConfiguration.java:564)
[error]         at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.JdepsTask.buildConfig(JdepsTask.java:603)
[error]         at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.JdepsTask.run(JdepsTask.java:557)
[error]         at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.JdepsTask.run(JdepsTask.java:533)
[error]         at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.Main.run(Main.java:64)
[error]         at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.Main$JDepsToolProvider.run(Main.java:73)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.spi.ToolProvider.run(ToolProvider.java:137)
[error]         at ru.eldis.toollauncher.ToolLauncher.runTool(ToolLauncher.java:68)
[error]         at ru.eldis.toollauncher.ToolLauncher.lambda$main$1(ToolLauncher.java:33)
[error]         at ru.eldis.toollauncher.ToolLauncher.main(ToolLauncher.java:48)
[error] java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit value: 1
[error]         at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:30)
[error]         at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.archetypes.jlink.JlinkPlugin$.runForOutput(JlinkPlugin.scala:212)
[error]         at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.archetypes.jlink.JlinkPlugin$.$anonfun$runJavaTool$2(JlinkPlugin.scala:197
[error]         at sbt.io.IO$.withTemporaryFile(IO.scala:534)
[error]         at sbt.io.IO$.withTemporaryFile(IO.scala:544)
[error]         at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.archetypes.jlink.JlinkPlugin$.runJavaTool(JlinkPlugin.scala:191)
[error]         at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.archetypes.jlink.JlinkPlugin$.$anonfun$projectSettings$11(JlinkPlugin.scala:53)
[error]         at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.archetypes.jlink.JlinkPlugin$.$anonfun$projectSettings$9(JlinkPlugin.scala:74)
[error]         at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:49)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:62)
[error]         at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(Transform.scala:68)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:282)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:23)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:291)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:282)
[error]         at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:265)
[error]         at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:64)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
[error]         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
[error] (jlinkModules) Nonzero exit value: 1
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed Sep 23, 2021, 11:57:58 AM
```

This error is a known problem with the *JlinkPlugin*, but we have already applied the recommended "fix" (the definition of the `jlinkModulePath` setting—see below) and it doesn't appear to resolve the problem. Running `show jlinkModulePath` within *SBT* results in the following:

```
[info] * C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Coursier\Cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\com\thoughtworks\paranamer\paranamer\2.8\paranamer-2.8.jar
```

so that looks OK.

Any suggestions?

Here's the relevant portions of our `build.sbt` file:

```scala
// Enable the Windows installer plugin.
//
// Note: This plugin requires that WiX Toolkit be installed to create the Windows installation
// script.
enablePlugins(WindowsPlugin)

// Enable the Java JLink plugin.
//
// This adds a Java installation to the web-application's installer file.
enablePlugins(JlinkPlugin)

// Package installation settings for Windows.
maintainer := "Me <me@emycompany.com>"
Windows / name := "MyProduct-" + version.value
Windows / packageSummary := "My web app"
Windows / packageDescription := """Windows installer for the My Web-Application."""

// WiX Toolkit product and upgrade GUIDs.
//
// DO NOT CHANGE THESE VALUES!
//
// NOTE: These are not the actual values. Doh!
wixProductId := "someproductguid"
wixProductUpgradeId := "someproductupgradeguid"

// Configure the Windows BAT file's JVM configuration file location.
batScriptConfigLocation  := Some("%APP_HOME%\\conf\\jvmopts-bat")

// Configure JLink so that it knows where to find the "paranamer" module (that is not a typo: it really is "paranamer",
// not "parameter").
jlinkModulePath := {
  // Get the full classpath with all the resolved dependencies.
  fullClasspath.in(jlinkBuildImage).value
  // Find the ones that have `paranamer` as their names.
  .filter { item =>
    item.get(moduleID.key).exists { modId =>
      modId.name == "paranamer"
    }
  }
  // Get raw `File` objects.
  .map(_.data)
}

// Make jLink output a little smaller, by removing elements we do not require.
jlinkOptions ++= Seq(
  "--no-header-files",
  "--no-man-pages",
  "--compress=2"
)
```